# Is it bad to create a global wxCriticalSection variable in wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, multithreading, wxwidgets

I am using `wxTreeListCtrl` to display a tree. For every expansion of a tree node I am creating one thread which calls backend API and returns with response. After execution of every thread, a `HandleExpansionRequest()` is executed which adds response elements to tree. These operations are working fine.

Problem is:
case 1: when thread is executing backend functions, meanwhile if user closes main frame, then execution of `wxQueueEvent` in `Entry()` gives exception. 
To solve this problem: 
Instead of deleting threads when window is closed, I am using a variable `isFrameClosed` and checking it before thread creates a `wxQueueEvent` for main code. My doubt is, is this a good way to stop crashing of program after frame closes but threads are still executing(as I am creating global `wxCriticalSection` ) ?

```
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame)
EVT_TREELIST_ITEM_EXPANDED(wxID_ANY, MyFrame::OnItemExpand)   
EVT_THREAD(ITEM_BROWSE_WORKER_EVENT,MyFrame::OnExpandThreadCompletion)
END_EVENT_TABLE()

//using below 2 variables to avoid crash when item expansion request is sent and user closes the frame.
 wxCriticalSection cs_forisFrameClosed;
 static bool isFrameClosed;

MyFrame::MyFrame()
{
   {
    wxCriticalSectionLocker lock(cs_forisFrameClosed);
    isFrameClosed = false;
   }
   //remaining code ...
}

MyFrame::~MyFrame()
{
   {
    wxCriticalSectionLocker lock(cs_forisFrameClosed);
    isFrameClosed = true;
   }
}

void MyFrame::OnItemExpand(wxTreeListEvent& event)
{
     MyThread *thread = new MyThread(this);
    if (thread->Create() != wxTHREAD_NO_ERROR)
    {
        PrintError(__FUNCTION__, "Can't create thread!");
    }
    thread->Run();
}

MyThread::MyThread(MyFrame *frame) : wxThread()
{
    m_frame = frame;
}

wxThread::ExitCode MyThread::Entry()
{
    string resp;
    GetResponseFromBackEnd(resp);
    {
        wxCriticalSectionLocker lock(cs_forisFrameClosed);
        if (!isFrameClosed)
        {
            wxThreadEvent event(wxEVT_THREAD, ITEM_BROWSE_WORKER_EVENT);
            event.SetString(resp);
            wxQueueEvent(m_frame, event.Clone());
        }
    }
}


void MyFrame::OnExpandThreadCompletion(wxThreadEvent &event)
{
    // this function is executed after every thread returns.
    // take response from event and update tree with children.      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As [the docs](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/classwx_thread.html) say, detached threads delete themselves, so you can't delete them because it would result in doing it twice. Instead, you must implement some way of communicating with the thread and ask it to quit when it's time to do it. [wxMessageQueue](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/classwx_message_queue_3_01_t_01_4.html) provides one of the simplest ways to do it.

Comment: In addition, the [thread sample](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/samples/thread/thread.cpp) gives an example of using a bool variable and a semaphore in the app class to ensure that the threads are deleted when the frame is closed.

Comment: I have edited my question, created a global `WxCriticalSection` and `isFrameClosed`.I am making `isFrameClosed = false` in constructor and `true` in destructor. & checking `isFrameClosed` in every thread entry() before executing `wxQueueEvent`. It has solved my problem. But is it a good way to declare this wxCriticalSection as a global parameter ?

Comment: @VZ can you please check edited question. I found a solution, but I am not sure whether it is a good coding practice or not.

Comment: This should really be a new question, it has nothing to do with the original one. To answer, in short: it's unsafe, your code can crash if the event is sent just before the frame being destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to join() all of the spawned threads in your close method.

Comment: I can't use join, because main program window freezes as back-end api takes more time to respond.